# How to Change the Title of Action-Bar?

Tags: android, navigation, components

I am creating an App and using navigation component, so if main fragment is inflated, the action-bar title is the main fragment when it is navigated to firstDestination fragment action-bar title must be firstDestination.
How could I do that?

Comment: is this you looking for?        Objects.requireNonNull(getSupportActionBar()).setTitle("whatever");

Comment: Just use the label in your graph

Answer (score 0):

Just use the `android:label` in your navigation graph:

```
<navigation xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    app:startDestination="@id/firstFragment">
    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/firstFragment"
        android:label="First Fragment Title"
        .../>

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/secondFragment"
        android:label="Second Fragment Title"
        .../>
</navigation>
```